# ModuleNotFound: flask_httpauth

Tags: python

I am trying to use flask_httpauth for my flask app just like it is documented in [here](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I made sure to use `pip install flask_httpauth` while in the virtual environmnent.
Yet I encounter the ModuleNotFound error for `from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth` and I can't seem to find the reason why.
The import for `from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash` is working fine and so do all other imports too.

I am still new to working on unix systems so I don't know if there could be a problem because I have my project folder under opt/
So maybe there are some restrictions that I don't know about why I can't use it.

Okay so I have Python3.10.4 and Pip22.0.2.
Also used pipdeptree to see the installed packages and it gave me something like this: [pipdeptree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOpBq.png)

I created a service that starts the app and I also make sure to restart it when I am doing any changes. Calls to the app are with curl and just simple GET requests.

Another edit:
I didn't know about the which python and which pip before so I thought you wanted to just know the versions, my bad.
Both of them my python and pip are under home/user/project/venv/bin/
I would assume maybe it should have been opt/project/venv/bin/ gonna look into how I change that. The typo was from when I typed it in here, sorry, in my code it is without the typo.

I use nginx together with flask and followed the steps from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) to also include a systemd service. So under /etc/systemd/system/project.service I have `ExecStart=/opt/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini` like it should be under Step 5 of the documentation.
The project.ini is identical to what you see under Step 4 only with a drifferent chmod-socket and I added touch-reload = /opt/project/project.py to have the service restart when I do changes to my code.
Executing `(venv):/opt/project/$python project.py` gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAHTy.png)
and executing the curl GET request returns with an Internal Server Error.
Looking into it with `sudo journalctl -u project` it tells me "no python application found" with the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_httpauth' above and that's also what is highlighted in my vscode

Comment: I think you might find your answer [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

its possible that you arent running the app using the virtual environment

just type `python` and `import flask_httpauth`. if it works, you're not using the venv to run your project.
if the import fails, you didnt install the package in your venv

`sudo python` (or `sudo python flask.py` to run your app) is a different venv

everything needs to use the same venv (or no venv)